# faced_wrap plot with pROC package in R (several variables)

Tags: r, ggplot2, roc, proc-r-package

I have three independent variable and a single binary outcome variable. I'm using `pROC` package for the analysis and would like to present all three ROC plots next to each other, similar to `face_wrap` functionality. For example, using the following code,

```
library(pROC)
data(aSAH)
roc_i <- roc(aSAH$outcome,
             aSAH$s100b,
             legacy.axes=TRUE,
             ci=TRUE, 
             boot.n=2000, 
             ci.alpha=0.9, 
             stratified=TRUE,
             plot=TRUE, 
             auc.polygon=TRUE, 
             max.auc.polygon=TRUE, 
             grid=TRUE,
             print.auc=TRUE, 
             print.thres='best', 
             print.thres.best.method='y',
             print.thres.adj=c(-0.05, 1.25),#,c(-0.05, 2.0),c(-0.05, 5.0)),
             print.thres.pattern="Cut-off: %.3f \n\nSp: %.3f \nSe: %.3f",
             print.thres.pattern.cex = 1.5,
             print.auc.cex = 1.5,
             print.auc.y=0.2,
             print.auc.x=0.8,
             cex.axis=1.5,
             cex.lab=1.5,
             print.thres.pch=16,
             print.thres.cex=2.0,
             cex.main=1.5)
```

I can generate a single picture for a single independent variable `s100b`, while I need two more (for other ind. Var 2 and ind. Var 3) and plot next to each other, like this for example:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to use the [ggroc function of pROC](https://rdrr.io/cran/pROC/man/ggroc.html)?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(pROC)

data(aSAH)
roc.list <- roc(outcome ~ s100b + ndka + wfns, data = aSAH)

g <- ggroc(roc.list)
g
```

[image]

```
g + facet_grid(.~name) + theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

You will still need to add the extra information manually though.

Comment: Great solution, thanks. On the same note: is it possible to create three panels (as in above), while there is ONE independent variable (X), and three various (binary) outcomes?. For example, a single (continuous) biomarker and three different binary outcomes (three not related diseases)

Comment: so each panel should display an ROC curve of the same biomarker for each of diseases, rather than the same binary outcome as function of three biomarkers (as you presented in above). The opposite problem.

Comment: Not directly I think, but you can use the ggroc function as a starting point.